# Файловый ввод в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как эффективно организовать ввод данных в python 3.1, например такого вида:

> `текстовый файл input.txt
>   5 
>   23 43 45 32 12`

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду под словом "эффективный"? Почему просто open не подходит?

Answer (score 2):

Решение в лоб:

```
s := raw_input()
d = filter(None, s.split(" "))
```

теперь в d list вида ['23', '43', '45', '32', '12'].

---- upd ----

а ещё можно добавить такой вызов

```
r = map(int, d)
```

теперь в r будут не строки, а уже числа [23, 43, 45, 32, 12]